# Problema con el indizador al ser de solo lectura C#

Tags: c#

Declaro lo siguiente:

```
public string caracter  = new string(new char[1]);
```

Pero al llamarlo más adelante y al tratar de darle un valor  no me deja y me saca un error de indizador

```
caracter[0] = 27; //No me deja darle valores me saca el error
```

> No se puede asignar a la propiedad o el indizador 'string.this[int]' porque es de solo lectura

Agradezco alguna ayuda, muchas gracias

Comment: A pesar de que colocaste el código de lo que intentas hacer no indicas qué quieres hacer o lograr, quieres definir un string array?

Comment: La idea es definir un string array, que me permita recibir valores numéricos que se le manden, poderlos leer y operar más adelante, es para poder implementar un algoritmo que lee números e imprime el valor en letras.

Comment: Por lo que veo es un problema de indizador, pero no se como indizar al tenerlo de esta forma:

Comment: que es un string array?

Comment: y porque hay que definir un array de strings si vas a recibir numeros? no seria mejor un array de numeros?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para definir un string array debes hacerlo de las siguientes formas

```
string[] s_arr = new string[] { "A", "B", "C" };
```

o

```
string[] s_arr = new string[3];
s_arr[0] = "A";
s_arr[1] = "B";
s_arr[2] = "C";
```

Si necesitas mas información puedes revisar el enlace siguiente https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/single-dimensional-arrays

Answer (score 2):

Las cadenas (`string`) en C# son inmutables. Esto quiere decir que no se pueden modificar una vez creadas.

Podrías usar `StringBuilder`, de la siguiente manera:

```
StringBuilder caracter= new StringBuilder("");
caracter[0] = (char)27;
```

Aunque si, como parece, lo que quieres es almacenar un caracter, por que no usar directamente `char`?

```
char c;
c=(char)27;
```

**Editado**

Tras leer tu comentario, otra opción mas lógica si lo que quieres es un array de caracteres, es usar una colección de char:

```
char[] caracteres = new char[10];
caracteres[6] = 's';
```

**Editado 2**

> es para poder implementar un algoritmo que lee números e imprime el valor en letras

En ese caso, lo que debes hacer es almacenar los numeros la colección (array, `List`..) y solo convertirlos a su representación posteriormente.

```
int[] numeros= new int[numerodeelementos];

o

List<int> numeros = new List<int>();
```

Comment: se pueden modificar haciendo un replace ;) pero no directamente.. solo como aclaracion antes que alguien diga si se puede...

Comment: @gbianchi cierto, pero `Replace` devuelve una nueva cadena, no la antigua...